# Create javascript object dynamically (Backbone View)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

The context here is Backbone but it's a general question about dynamically creating javascript objects.

I would like to pass the name of a View ('ViewX') to be created, to a function which can then invoke the View constructor: `new ViewX()`

How could I do this?

Some more context:

In my Backbone View I want to create a subview, the type of which depends on the Model I have used for the current View.

At the moment I have a non-dynamic if-else approach (See Approach #1 in the example) which works, but is clunky and will be more clunky in future when I have more Model types.

I have tried some dynamic approaches to creating the subview, including evaluation via the Function constructor (Approach #2), which gives 'string is not a function' error.

In Approach #3, the View module I am passing as a parameter is not available in the current View's `this` namespace (I am using requirejs).

```
renderContentList: function() {

    var self = this;

    // Approach #1
    var setSidebarListCollectionView = function(type) {
       if (type === 'tags') {
           self.sidebarListCollectionView = new TagSidebarListCollectionView({
               collection: self.collection,
               tagCollection: self.tagCollection
           });
       } else {
           self.sidebarListCollectionView = new CardSidebarListCollectionView({
               collection: self.collection,
               tagCollection: self.tagCollection
           });
       }
    };
    /*
    // Approach #2
    var setSidebarListCollectionView = new Function('type', 'coll', 'tagColl', 'return new type({collection: coll, tagCollection: tagColl});');

    // Approach #3
    var setSidebarListCollectionView = function(type) {
        return new self[type]({
                        collection: self.collection,
                        tagCollection: self.tagCollection
                    });
    };
    */
    // reset it every time
    if (this.sidebarListCollectionView) {
        this.sidebarListCollectionView.remove();
    }
    if (this.model.get('activeSubTab') === 'tags') {
        // Approach #1
        setSidebarListCollectionView('tags');
        // Approach #2
        // this.sidebarListCollectionView = setSidebarListCollectionView('TagSidebarListCollectionView', this.collection, this.tagCollection);
        // Approach #3
        // this.sidebarListCollectionView = setSidebarListCollectionView('TagSidebarListCollectionView');
    } else {
        // Approach #1
        setSidebarListCollectionView('cards');
        // Approach #2
        // this.sidebarListCollectionView = setSidebarListCollectionView('CardSidebarListCollectionView', this.collection, this.tagCollection);
        // Approach #3
        // this.sidebarListCollectionView = setSidebarListCollectionView('CardSidebarListCollectionView');
    }

    // render the list of content title links.
    this.$el.find('#content-manager-list-content').append(this.sidebarListCollectionView.render().el);
},
```

I have asked this question over at [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90081/dynamically-create-javascript-object-backbone-view), but perhaps SO is a better fit for it.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can achieve this is by making extending `Backbone.Events`.

1.Create a controller object that extends `Backbone.Events`.
2.Define custom events for each view creation.
3.Trigger the appropriate custom event to create a view.

```
var AppViewBus = _.extend({},Backbone.Events);  

AppViewBus.on("showview:ViewX",function(payload){
    // Load data if required.
    // Create a view instance passing the loaded data.
    // Render the view.
});

AppViewBus.on("showview:ViewY",function(payload){
    // Load data if required.
    // Create a view instance passing the loaded data.
    // Render the view.
});
```

Now wherever you need to create a new view dynamically you can do something like below since you already know what view you want to create.

```
var payload = {
    // Add properties that you probably require to pass 
    // down to your controller method
};
AppViewBus.trigger("showview:ViewX",payload);
```

You can also reuse these methods from the `router callbacks` too making your code more reusable and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it's interesting - but I think it is moving what I'm already doing to a different part of the app.